# How to improve content for tag 'mlrun'?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Can you provide me recommendation, how to improve/tune the content for tag [mlrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mlrun)?

I created the [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34185356)

> MLRun is an open source helper/framework based on Python for speedup
> delivery from ML/AI experiment phase to production with focus on
> minimalizing development effort (agnostic approach without focus on a
> specific AI/ML topic).
>
> It supports MLOps with featurestore concept, including continuous
> training and continuous monitoring also. It is based on K8s with
> ability to support scalability of AI/ML in on-prem and cloud (support
> of main three major cloud providers).
>
> Sample of python code:
>
> ```
> import mlrun
> import mlrun.feature_store as fstore
>
> # create project 'test'
> project = mlrun.get_or_create_project("test", context="./")
>
> # add feature set (part of feature store) 
> transaction_set = fstore.FeatureSet("transaction", entities=[fstore.Entity("trid")])
>
> # ingest data
> fstore.ingest(transaction_set, bank_trn, infer_options=fstore.InferOptions.default())
> ```
>
> **More information**
>
> - License 'Apache-2.0 license'
> - Official web [see](https://www.mlrun.org/)
> - Git web [see](https://github.com/mlrun/mlrun)
> - Documentation web [see](https://docs.mlrun.org/)

and [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34185357):

> open source helper/framework based on Python for speedup delivery of ML/AI to the production (support MLOps with featurestore concept), main focus on kubernetes solution. Use this tag for questions about platform MLRun (e.g. MLRun CE, MLRun paid version) or libraries from this solution (e.g. v3io, v3io stream, storey).

Based on earlier [feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423970) I've applied the recommendations:

- without copy paste, based on own experience (but you can see here a few business buzzwords also :-( )
- I mentioned usage and technical platform (k8s)
- I added sample (it can help)
- I added references to useful sources

Please, let me know, how to tune or if something is not the best.

Comment: Mostly looks good, assuming all the content is actually correct. Could do with being proofread/run through a grammar checker. The excerpt fails to provide usage guidance.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine, may I mention e.g. usecases (but it can be everything from AI/ML, agnostic usage)?

Comment: @JIST I mean the excerpt should include usage guidance for the tag itself e.g. Which questions should include the tag, any other appropriate tags that should be used in addition to it. And it shouldn't just say "Use this tag for questions about mlrun" it should be more specific than that, for example for questions relating to the debugging of mlrun x, y, and z's

Comment: It is worth reading https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/  as it has *a few words of advice on writing tag wiki excerpts:*

Comment: @rene, Is it good place here (in META) to open the question about improvement/tuning new tag (or it is inconvenient topic)?

Comment: There is not other place to go, right? The question and answer format is ill-suited for collaborative editing as you can see with these comments here, going back and forth with improvements. Nothing else we can do about it.

Comment: For the Code Sample, could maybe better use 3x Backticks (`\`\`\``) instead of 4x Indents, that would allow to add a `lang-py` (not sure if correct Code?) to force Python Syntax Highlighting (if Syntax Highlighting is ueberhaupt supported in Tag Wikis(?), not sure about that), or the Default `lang-html` will otherwise probably get applied...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253046/discussion-between-jist-and-chivracq).

Comment: About Syntax Highlighting, [Editing-Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Page in the 'Help Center' + [this Thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/642998) on 'MSE'. // => Basically need to add a `\`\`\`python` or `\`\`\`lang-python` or `\`\`\`lang-py` before your Code Block and a `\`\`\`` after. // Or can add a `<!-- language: lang-py -->` (+ empty Return Line) before the Code Block, and this "*older*" Syntax does (still?) work with your 4-Space Indented Syntax, and also does work in Tag Wikis, as I'm not sure if the 'Code-Fence' Syntax works/is supported in Tag Wikis...

Comment: @chivracq, I repaired all (typo plus lang-python in original tag)

Comment: Yep, good...!, and "good news" is that Syntax Highlighting seems to work then in Tag Wikis, even for "smaller" Tags that don't have a Default `lang-code`, I can see some different Colours for the `import` Command + Comments + Strings between Double Quotes... (Visible on your '[Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34185356)' from the `Inline` + `Side-by-side` Views... (I wasn't sure about that and nbd else confirmed...))